# How to get a list of Site Level workflows in SharePoint using Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell

How do I get all site level workflows in SharePoint on-Prem (v 2013 and above)? I see a lot of posts on enumerating workflows related to lists but not really for site workflows. Preferably something using Powershell

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: Should mention that $spweb.WorkflowAssociations does not yield anything. But I can see the site workflow through the UI.

Comment: I am not sure why these are not visible via powershell but as a workaround, I was able to query the wfsvc List in each spweb and select the workflows that were not previously identified as a list workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with it and the $spweb.workflowassociations returns information of workflow. 
[image]

Have you tested with other sites in different web applications?

Comment: Jerry - I can get the site workflows on a few sites with the same code. But even on those sites, it shows some of the site workflows and not all. Any idea why I would not be seeing some or all site workflows? This is indeed strange.